# How do I give a browser window or tab a "name" after it's been opened?

Tags: html, browser, window.open

I have an application that is a portal which links to other apps.  The links open up those apps with a target='app-name' so that if they open it again and the window exists, it opens in the same window.

However, while in the app, we have a link to go back to the portal window but that window has no 'target=portal' tag...it opened up first - let's say via a bookmark. So when the link is clicked, we get a new portal tab/window...now we have two.  The users want us to find the existing one.

So how do I 'name' the portal window so I can get back to it with a target='portal'?

Comment: Can you take the <title> from the HTML page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
window.name = 'portal';
```

According to [MDN article about `window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.name),

> Gets/sets the name of the window.
>   
>   The name of the window is used primarily for setting targets for hyperlinks and forms.

Be aware it's DOM Level 0, not part of any standard.

Comment: That was promising but it doesn't work. I verified that the window.name was being set to 'portal' but it still isn't recognized in the target.

Comment: @richinator38 It works for me on firefox. Try setting both `window.name` and `target` to the same value in this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/R5K8C/)

Comment: I got it working! I just wasn't linking to my app from that page locally but once I did that, it worked.  Except for Firefox.  Will have to look into that. Thanks!